# How can I set body in action

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to set body after move delay, I am searching something like runBlock in sprite-kit.

```
void MySprite::SpawnSprite( cocos2d::Layer *layer )
{
    auto mySprite = Sprite::create();
    auto body = PhysicsBody::create();

    mySprite->setTexture("MySprite.png");        
    body->createCircle(arrow->getContentSize().width / 2);
    body->setDynamic(false);
    mySprite->setPosition( startPoint );
    layer->addChild(mySprite);

    auto moveTest = MoveTo::create(2, Point(200, 200) );
    auto waitAction = DelayTime::create(2);
    auto action = Sequence::create(moveTest, waitAction, NULL);//I want to set body after waitAction in sequence(mySprite->setPhysicsBody(body))
    mySprite->runAction(action);
}
```

This is so simple in sprite-kit

```
runAction(
    SKAction.sequence([
        action,
        SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0),
        SKAction.runBlock({ //Set Body }))
        ])
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void MySprite::SetBody(Sprite *sprite)
{
    auto body = PhysicsBody::create();
    body->createCircle(arrow->getContentSize().width / 2);
    body->setDynamic(false);
    sprite->setPhysicsBody(body);
}

void MySprite::SpawnSprite( cocos2d::Layer *layer )
{
    auto mySprite = Sprite::create();

    mySprite->setTexture("MySprite.png");        
    mySprite->setPosition( startPoint );
    layer->addChild(mySprite);

    auto moveTest = MoveTo::create(2, Point(200, 200) );
    auto waitAction = DelayTime::create(2);
    auto funcCallAction = CallFunc::create([=](){
            MySprite::SetBody(mySprite);
        });
    auto action = Sequence::create(moveTest, waitAction, funcCallAction, NULL);
    mySprite->runAction(action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create CallFuncN and use it in your sequence like this

Fist a function you need:

```
void attachBody(Ref* pSender)
{
Sprite* mySprite = (Sprite*)pSender;
mySprite->setPhysiceBody(body);
//you can do whatever you want to do with your sprite here.
}
```

Now you sequence would be something like this

```
auto action = Sequence::create(moveTest, waitAction,CallFuncN::create(CC_CALLBACK_1(attachBody,this)), NULL);
```

Comment: but I should create sprite and body in my SpawnSprite function, because I have a lot of same sprite. If I don't create in function all sprites are affected by my action right?

Comment: you want to attach body to the sprite, on which you ran sequence action?

Comment: yes, Maybe I can do it with object pooling. I will try.